# Phonegap can't use camera in iPad retina mini iOS7

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, camera

I've built an app in iPad. It's worked well in 2 iPads 2 (iOS 6.1 and iOS 7.1)
But, then I test on iPad retina mini iOS 7 (Model: ME820ZP/A), it's crashed when I choose photo or take a photo.

Here my phone gap code: `

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {

    // init for photo
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;


}


// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

  // Get image handle
  var imgAvatar = document.getElementById('avatar');

  // Unhide image elements
  imgAvatar.style.display = 'block';
  // add into img element
  imgAvatar.src = imageURI;

 // local storage
  window.localStorage.setItem('User_Avatar',imageURI);
}

// A button will call this function
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, allowEdit: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
}

// A button will call this function
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
function onFail(message) {
    showAlert("Có lỗi: " + message);
}

// alert dialog dismissed
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}
// Show a custom alert
//
function showAlert(message) {
    navigator.notification.alert(
        message,  // message
        alertDismissed,         // callback
        'Thông báo',            // title
        'OK'                  // buttonName
    );
}
```

`
Of course, the plugin org.apache.cordova.camera has added.

This's Debug Screen: http://thienhaxanh.info/debug-screen.png (sorry, I can't post images :) )

Thank you.

Comment: try with decrease camera quality

Comment: Hello @kathir, i've tried, but unsuccess. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try inline function.... It seems to be working most of the time I think...

```
function takeasnap() {
    try {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(

            function (uri) {
                alert(uri);
            },
            function (e) {
                console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
            }, {
                quality: 50
            }
        );
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: I call an alert before navigator...., it's worked. But, when call to navigator.camera.getPicture, it's not worked. I don't know why js not catch error. Do you have any ideas else?

Comment: can u pls take look in config.xml which will be under "Project/platforms/ios/Project/www/config.xml" and find whether the following code is there...
<dict>
<key>Plugins</key>
<string>CDVCamera</string>
</dict>

Add this to your config after "<name>...<name>" line.

Comment: It's still not working :( I think the problem only with my device. And I will ask Apple support team when I distribute app. So tired with this bug :(((

Comment: Cool @GBMtoàn... They will help u... dont forget to comment here about the solution... :)